# Color of setPixel

Tags: java

Found an example:

```
raster.setPixel( pf, jj, clr );
```

But *clr* has 4 elements:

```
static int[] clr = {0, 0, 0, 255};
```

Why? What does that 4th element mean? It doesn't work without it, throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: What type of object is raster?

Comment: @LaurentiuL. I believe it is a `WritableRaster`.

Comment: It's probably an alpha transparency value. 0 means fully transparent. 255 means no transparency. If you don't include it you probably get an index out of bounds exception when setPixel tries to read it and it isn't there

Comment: Thank you. Yes, WritableRaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, you confirmed that `raster` if of type `WritableRaster`.

First, for your exception

> It doesn't work without it, throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

From the documentation, an AIOOBE will be thrown if the coordinates are not in bounds, or if the given array is too small to hold the input.

Now for what represent the 4 input given in the array,

The input array define the sample for each bands of the raster. If you call for example, `WritableRaster#getNumBands` it should return 4.

But whare are the `bands` ?

Here a visual representation of what an array of 3 samples represent :

[image]

Now as for the fourth band, I'm pretty sure it is the alpha sample. Well, at least one of them is the alpha but we can't confirm which one is as you can modify the order of the bands when creating the raster.

Answer (score 2):

You have a [`WritableRaster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) which was created with a [`SampleModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/SampleModel.html) that requires four samples per pixel.

Without knowing more about your application (what exact `SampleModel` is the raster created with?), it is hard to say for sure what the fourth component means. It is most likely the alpha channel, which contains the opacity of the pixel, where 0 = transparent and 255 = fully opaque.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth argument is the transparency value.

### From the [documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html#setPixel(int,%20int,%20int[]))

> public void setPixel(int x, int y, int[] iArray)
>
> *Sets a pixel in the DataBuffer using an int array of samples for input. An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException may be thrown if the coordinates are not in bounds. However, explicit bounds checking is not guaranteed.*
>
> Parameters:
>
> x - The X coordinate of the pixel location.
>
> y - The Y coordinate of the pixel location.
>
> iArray - The input samples in a int array.
>
> Throws:
>   NullPointerException - if iArray is null.
>
> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - if the coordinates are not in bounds, or if iArray is too small to hold the input.

Generally when dealing with pixels you will have an X and Y value and then either 3 arguments for R, G, B or 4 arguments for R, G, B, **A**, where **A** is the alpha channel otherwise known as the opacity. It will take a value between 0 and 255 just like the RGB values.